# All list items are not Saved

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, list-form

I'm using SharePoint 2013 When I fill all fields and save it only lookup field and people picker field data is saved and remaining fields data is not saved in NewForm.aspx (default form).

Actually I want  two data fields on same line, so I'm using following code to merge two rows. But, after changing position of row that row data is not saved in list. Remaining data is saved. If I remove this code all fields are saved correctly, Manager Name and Requester name are single line text fields.

```
$("#firsttbl").after("<tr><td><div class='headerdiv'><span> Requested By </span></div><table id='secondtbl' class='innertableclass' border='0'></table></td></tr>");
temp = $("[class='ms-formlabel']").find("nobr:contains('Manager Name')").closest("tr").html();
$("[class='ms-formlabel']").find("nobr:contains('Manager Name')").closest("tr").remove();
$("[class='ms-formlabel']").find("nobr:contains('Requester Name')").closest("tr").append(temp);
temp = $("[class='ms-formlabel']").find("nobr:contains('Requester Name')").closest("tr").html();
$("[class='ms-formlabel']").find("nobr:contains('Requester Name')").closest("tr").remove();
$("#secondtbl").append("<tr>"+temp+"</tr>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's your .remove() statements. I've noticed that if you disable a list field, for example, the data in that list will not be saved.

Instead of removing,  use hide.

Or, another option. When I'm moving fields around, I get the full dom element I want, and then do an target.appendTo(source) - which if it has a single element is the same as a move.

Comment: Disable and hide is not working, But appendTo() worked. Thank you so much.